# Full Screen Caller Pictures & Full Screen Caller ID

Tags: android, screen, call

So I've been searching for some time on how to either replace the in
call screen or put something on top of it....the only solution I have
found thus far is to make my own ROM, which doesn't make sense for
such a small portion of an OS.  however I found these two apps (Full
Screen Caller Pictures and Full Screen Caller ID) that are able to put
a contact image and button on top of the standard in call screen.

I don't know exactly what either of these developers have done, but
hope someone on the forums does.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

extend BroadcastReceiver class, set to boot, and then add the listener onReceive

```
TelephonyManager telephonymanager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        PhoneStateListener listener = new Listener();
        telephonymanager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

code of Listener:

```
class Listener extends PhoneStateListener {

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (state) {

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    break;


                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // do sth 
                    break;
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    }
```